# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: parse_str() expects exactly 2 arguments, 1 given. How do i update for latest php version?

Tags: php, query-string, php-8

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);  

if ($m == ""){
  $dateComponents = getdate();
  $month = $dateComponents['mon'];
  $year = $dateComponents['year'];
} else {
  $month = $m;
  $year = $y;
}

echo build_previousMonth($month, $year, $monthString);
// ... etc
```

Comment: How is the rest of the code in your example relevant to the question?

Comment: it shows its part of a calendar script but probably not relevent. Tried to remove but site wont allow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original implementation of [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) - and the particular way it was often used - was, to say the least, quite naive. The problem is that, when called without second argument, this function essentially allowed polluting the local symbol table. Here's an extract of [CVE Vulnerability Description](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2007-3205/):

> The parse_str function in (1) PHP, (2) Hardened-PHP, and (3) Suhosin,
> when called without a second parameter, might allow remote attackers
> to overwrite arbitrary variables by specifying variable names and
> values in the string to be parsed. NOTE: it is not clear whether this
> is a design limitation of the function or a bug in PHP, although it is
> likely to be regarded as a bug in Hardened-PHP and Suhosin.

That's why omitting second argument was deprecated in PHP 7.2 and dropped completely in PHP 8.0. Thus you need to reimplement this call so that the result is stored in a variable, and instead of checking `$m`, `$y`, ... directly, you check elements of associative array stored in that variable instead.

For example:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query);
if (empty($query['m'])) {
   // no data passed
}
else {
   $month = $query['m']; 
   // etc
}
```

---

As a sidenote, I'm really not sure why do you even have to parse query string, and not just use [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) directly.

Answer (score 0):

For `parse_str()` requires two parameters one is input and another one is output

Eg:

```
$QUERY_STRING = "first=value&second=scvalue";

parse_str($QUERY_STRING, $output_array)
```

here `$output_array` contains the query string data as associate array and can be accessed like parameter name like `$first_val = $output_array['first']`

Please check the link for `parse_str()` documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php